# Exist a better location for binaries in composer's projects?

Tags: php, composer-php

I always "fix" bin directory with

```
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
}
```

to keep al binaries in the same directory. I like consistency. Have som ./bin/foo and some other ./vendor/bin/foo for me is not in order. Are there some best practice or official principle to follow here?

Comment: There isn't. Personally, I prefer that binaries are in `vendor/bin/` not in `bin/`. If you prefer to have it in `bin/`, then as you said yourself - be consistent and that's it.

Comment: well the best practice it to keep vendor provided things in vendor dir and project files in project structure. However, I do understand your point but in that case you can just do some workarounds like symlinking (don't change the vendor bin dir itself) or what I do is simply wrap all bins and scripts of the project in composer tasks, that way i have a single consistent point of entry and all the pathing is hidden under composer